# Variables avaible in macros

Tags: excel, variables, vba

What are the types of identifying a cell as far i know it is

Sheet#.Cells(var,position) or Range(A1) are there any other types of identifying a cell.

Also I know how to increment Sheet#.Cells(var,position) but how do i increment Range(A1) in macros using while loop and any other mode?

I am trying to pick values based on condition from master sheet and populate output sheet row by row.

When I use Sheet#.Cells(var,position) it messes with the position when I get inconsistent data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get right what you need. However...
In Excel you can use something like this:

```
Range("E10").Offset(row_move, column_move)
```

where `row_move` allows to offset in both top/bottom direction, `column_move` offset to left/right direction. To move top/left direction you need to use values <0.

There is other option which I personally don't like:

```
Range("A" & row)
```

but as you can see it's easy to change row position in that situation and more difficult to change column.